# vs2012 load test doesn't start up many threads

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, visual-studio-2012

I have built a webtest.

In it I have added writing to file.

I have created loadtest with 5 virtual users that runs only the above webtest.

In the `Graph view` I see there were 5 `Users load`.

At the end I see only one line written to the file.

Do I need to define the distribution in some special way?

I thought setting the number of virtual users is enough. no?

btw, what can cause my loadtest to run exactly 10 minute on every run?

I don't remember limiting it to 10 min

this is my test code:

public class Settings_CacheExplosion : WebTest
    {
        //private static readonly ILog activityLog = LogManager.GetLogger("Activity");

```
    private static int _ctidsCounter { get; set; }

    public static int CtidsCounter
    {
        get
        {
            if (_ctidsCounter == 2000)
            {
                _ctidsCounter = 1000;
            }
            return _ctidsCounter++;
        }
        set
        {
            _ctidsCounter = value;
        }
    }

    public Settings_CacheExplosion()
    {
        this.PreAuthenticate = true;

        CtidsCounter = 1000;

        //log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
    }


    public override IEnumerator<WebTestRequest> GetRequestEnumerator()
    {
        WebTestRequest request1 = new WebTestRequest("http://clientservice.mam.qasite-services.com/settings");

        request1.Method = "POST";

        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("ctid={0}", CtidsCounter));

        request1.QueryStringParameters.Add("ctid", CtidsCounter.ToString(), false, false);
        StringHttpBody request1Body = new StringHttpBody();
        request1Body.ContentType = "";
        request1Body.InsertByteOrderMark = false;
        request1Body.BodyString = "";
        request1.Body = request1Body;

        string path = @"Settings_CacheExplosion_log.txt";
        // This text is added only once to the file. 
        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            // Create a file to write to. 
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(string.Format("ctid={0}", CtidsCounter));
            }
        }

        // This text is always added, making the file longer over time 
        // if it is not deleted. 
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(string.Format("ctid={0}", CtidsCounter));
        }   


        yield return request1;
        request1 = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: did the new lines overwrite or append to the file?

Comment: I think your test is running exactly 10 minutes (default load test duration) because you have the [Use Test Iterations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff406976.aspx#loadtestrunsettingproperties_testiterations) `False`. Set this property to `True` to run according the test iterations and not the test duration

Comment: @mcalex this was indeed the problem

Comment: @Schaliasos you were right. but yet it says `5 users load` and in my log files are more than 30 lines (some reapeating lines)

Comment: turned it into an answer, then  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that your writing method isn't overwriting the existing entries.  You'll need to use the append option if there is already text in the file.

Comment: you were right. but yet it says 5 users load and in my log files are more than 30 lines (some reapeating lines)

Comment: Are you deleting the entries from the file between each test?

Comment: hmm, maybe a new question showing the code that inserts the text is needed